# Change DataTrigger binding reference at runtime

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've a ListView with this DataTrigger attached:

```
<Style x:Key="HideShowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <localConverters:ShowHideConverter x:Key="ShowHideConverter" />
        </Style.Resources>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource showHideConverter}">
                        <Binding Path="EndingDate" />
                        <Binding Path="UserName" />
                        <Binding ElementName="SearchBox" Path="Text" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>

            <DataTrigger Value="false">
               (...)
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

I use this in a hardcoded scenario to hide/show some ListItems in the ListView. The binding source is specified in the ElementName tag, and the TextBox referred is declared a few lines before. 
Now, I've the necessity to change that Binding at runtime with another field incapsulated in a istantiated class. I've tried to use WPF class instead of XAML, but nothing, I don't have any clue how to obtain this.

I'm open to any advice! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var style = (Style)FindResource("HideShowStyle");
var trigger = (DataTrigger)style.Triggers[0];
var multibinding = (MultiBinding)trigger.Binding;

var binding1 = (Binding)multibinding.Bindings[0];
var binding2 = (Binding)multibinding.Bindings[1];
var binding3 = (Binding)multibinding.Bindings[2];
```

Change bindings at will.